# Custom query - Average answers per user question

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to craft a DataExplorer query  that shows:

1) **How many questions a particular user has answered**

2)  **The average number of *other* answers to those questions. (e.g. by other users)**

The first seems simple enough;

> **SELECT COUNT(*)
>
>   FROM Posts
>
>   WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##**

but the second bit is giving me trouble.

Comment: What would this prove?

Comment: @gone - Is "proving something" a necessary function of every query?

Comment: of course not, was just curious

Comment: My original question showed some more info about my intention. My concern is that when a high-rep user answers a question, it actively discourages lower-rep users from answering. By looking at the average number of answers as a whole (1.6 per question) and comparing those to the average number of answers per question answered by high-rep users, I can see whether this is a real effect or merely my imagination.

Comment: Okay, yes, that does sound like an interesting query and it actually sounds like something that probably needs to be looked at.

Comment: @Gone - Interestingly, when I put this info in the original post, it immediately attracted two downvotes. Removing it seems to have attracted two upvotes.

Comment: That in itself is an intriguing pattern - maybe some wording riled people - are certain keywords downvote magnets?

Comment: Maybe it was the fact that there was simply extraneous information in the question. My edit has definitely streamlined what I was asking without losing any of the meaning

Comment: I've just applied this search to the top 10 users on Sci-fi SE. It looks like the average number of answers (where high-rep users have posted answers) is significantly higher than the average. 2.56 versus an average of 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of approaches, but the first one that jumped to me was to join the table against itself.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.Id) AS AnswerCount, COUNT(*) AS AnswersByAllUsers, COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT A.Id) AS Average
FROM Posts A
    INNER JOIN Posts B ON A.ParentId = B.ParentId
WHERE A.PostTypeId = 2
      AND B.PostTypeId = 2
      AND A.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
```

I think that should get what you're looking for. Note, of course, that this represents the number and average answers per post the user answered, and *not* the count and average of *other answers*. So you can simply subtract to find the result of that, if that's what you're looking for, or alternatively you could add `AND A.Id <> B.Id`, but that could have unintended consequences in certain circumstances. Although I doubt they'd matter much.

Comment: No. This is exactly what I wanted. Subtracting the original answers would remove my ability to construct a moving average.